# Getting error in storing the filename in the Azure Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am getting one excel file in data lake and I am exporting the excel file into Azure SQL database using Dataflow in the ADF.

I need to store the filename as a column in my data. I am following the below steps:

[image]

I am giving the column name called "filename" in the Column to store the file name section.

I can able to see the entire columns and my new column "filename" in the projection and inspect section. However, when I tried to see the preview data, I am getting the below error

[image]

Not sure what is the issue? I changed the column name but no success. Could anyone advise what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, there must be a column name **Filename** which already exists in the source file schema.

Your settings look correct and if you are facing the same error after changing the column name, try to refresh your dataset or remove and add the source dataset again. This can refresh your source schema if any to the latest.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you have a file inside a subfolder, the filename column extracts the full file path which includes subfolders and filename (ex: /subfolder/filename).

In this case, extract only filename from the filename column using derived column transformation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. After seeing your result, I checked. I have 5 sheets in each excel file. Already, I built the data flow for extracting one excel sheet with Filename. Now, it's not accepting the filename for the second excel sheet. Here I am creating a separate data flow for each excel sheet. I created a new linked service, a new data source, given a new filename and refresh multiple times, still no success. Is there any limitation of getting the filename for the same source of excel file? Are they any way around it? Thanks for your support